# System Monitor Causes Periodic Current Peaks When Open in RHEL/Centos 6

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux

While collecting data for a power consumption analysis, I noticed that simply having the System Monitor open while at idle caused periodic peaks in the current draw of the 12V bus.  The current draw flattened to idle once the Sys Monitor was closed, and resumed the periodic behavior when it was opened.  System monitor did not show a commensurate CPU load to coincide with the spikes.

Are these spikes a function of how the system monitor calculates its load?

[image: Plot of Current Draw]